# mapStateToProps not getting called at all

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a container which is subscribed to the store using mapStateToProps. I am able to change the state using reducers in this fashion

```
export default function firstReducer(state={}, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_USERNAME':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                username: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

However, mapStateToProps is not getting called even once. Where am I going wrong

```
export default class myComponent extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return(
            <h1>this.props.userName</h1>
       )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("Hey");
    return{
        userName: state.username
    };
}

export const myContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(myComponent);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `myContainer ` and not `myComponent`? You should not be exporting both. Especially if you are exporting `myComponent` as your default.

Comment: Minor detail: I think you're supposed to capitalised react component names, so it should be `MyComponent ` instead.

Comment: @Sulthan Is that responsible for mapStateToProps not getting called even once?

Comment: @D-reaper I have taken care of that. This is just a snippet i wrote for the question

Comment: @alchemist95 Can you check if 'ADD_USERNAME' action is actually received in the reducer?

Comment: @alchemist95 If you are exporting both that my bet is that you are using `myComponent` and not the container wrapped in `connect`. Show us how are you using that component.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Two things that you need to take care of

First have you component name not being with Uppercase letter and second remove the export default from the component, otherwise when you will be importing it as default you wouldn't be using the component that you have connected the store with

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return(
            <h1>this.props.userName</h1>
       )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("Hey");
    return{
        userName: state.username
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Comment: You made my day! After searching for so long, the soution was that easy :-) Thanks Dude!

Comment: Booooaaahhhhhhh !!!